# How to use different .xib files in the same class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I'm wondering if it's possible to create different nib files in IB and use one of these files at a time.

I just want to use different UICollectionView(s) that I've done in interface builder in the same view controller, switching between theme only changing the nib resource of the initialization.

Is it possible?
How?

Answer (score 0):

That could be done using the method initWithNibName:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNib" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: i was trying initWithNibName:bundle: but something it's not working, How i've to setup the xib?

Comment: Inside your xib, click on 'file owner' and in the right pane change your class to your view controller.

Comment: i get this error 
loaded the "flowLayout" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

thx

Comment: I want to show the view from there,
`TestViewController *viewController = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestViewController" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize view controllers with different nibs using [`initWithNibName:bundle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a).

So, for example:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It is quite possible to have different nib files for the same view controller class. Here, I'm listing two methods to load them programmatically and assigning the file owner as self - the current class.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNib" owner:self options:nil];


NSNib*    aNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"myNib" bundle:nil];
[aNib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil])
```